# Jquery Form submit will not reach MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

Note: Tested on Firefox and IE 11

I'm encountering a very weird issue here that doesn't seem to affect every account we have for testing. We have a Login form and once the user is logged in he can update the profile (which is part of the code you see below).

One account works perfectly fine, the submit button is clicked and it reaches the JS `onclick` event I'm displaying below, it then lands on the controller as expected.

Now, two other accounts, with similar data (nothing too different) submit the form and the click event fires but once it submits the form, it never reaches the controller.

Any ideas on what can be causing this?

**JS File (Trimmed for simplicity)**

```
//All arguments coming in are true
if (isValidGeneral && isValidAgentTypes && isValidAgentCodes && isValidCountrySelect && isValidTitleSelect && phoneNumbersValid ) {

                obj.preventDefault();
                $('#ProfileUpdateForm').submit();
                return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AgentProfileUpdate", "AgentProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "ProfileUpdateForm" }))
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile update failed")
     <div>
         <fieldset> ....Lots Of Fields... </fieldset>
     </div>

     <div id="submitButtonsDiv">
          <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" class="btnProfileUpdateSubmit" tabindex="56" />

          <input type="button" value="CANCEL" class="btnProfileUpdateCancel" tabindex="57" onclick="document.location.href=document.referrer"  />
     </div>
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error message in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: @Michael_B No errors showing up.

Comment: show the controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, clearing temp files and re-opening VS fixed it.

Comment: Kindly use comments section for comments